# Visual Basic 2010 - Get specific files in selected local drive

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I created a system that backup its database in available hard drive. Now my problem is how can I get all that files in the user selected local drive and display it in a list. The files I want to get is .bak files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will find all .bak files in C:\Temp and add their names to a ListBox named ListBox1.

```
Dim targetDirectory As String = "C:\Temp"

Dim fileEntries As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "*.bak")

Dim fileName As String
For Each fileName In fileEntries
    ListBox1.Items.Add(fileName)
Next fileName
```